# How to stop google from caching magento site?

Tags: magento, caching

I tried to put the no archive command into the head.phtml file but this doesn't work.
What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: What exactly did you try, and how much time did you give Google to actually get the info?

Answer (score 1):

try to create a robot.txt file into your web root folder or magento folder installation and put inside

First solution in robot.txt file

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Second Solution in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} AltaVista [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} msnbot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Slurp
RewriteRule ^.*$ "http\:\/\/htmlremix\.com" [R=301,L]
```

Information based on the article [Block Google and bots using htaccess and robots.txt](http://www.htmlremix.com/seo/block-google-and-bots-using-htaccess-and-robots-txt)

Comment: I got a robot txt file already.
I think your suggestion will prevent google from indexing my site and thus remove it from the search results.
All I want is to prevent google users from accessing cached pages of my site through google.

Comment: Curious, that's the official solution from Google itself http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1061943 or show my second solution in my answer

Comment: Hmm, robots.txt should tell the Googlebot to go away, so wouldn't it deny the caching operation anyway? Either way, if OP owns the website, he can use Google Webmaster Tools to remove cached content in results. [See here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=59819)

Comment: Ah ok sorry, I though he didn't want to index which it was curious for me. I didn't read correctly the title.

Comment: Yes, if you block googlebot with robots.txt it will chase it away, but will stop google from indexing your page as well.
I want my page to come up in google searches, but I don't want the cache to be available to users.

Comment: Probably it was already cached and you have to remove it from Google http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1663691 and by using the meta tag `noarchive` it will works after to have been removed. Don't you think?

Comment: The reason I'm doing this because I have blocked a range of ip addresses and I also don't want them to be able to access the google cache of our site.
Maybe there is another way to do this?